# How to convert the Firebase ServerValue.timestamp() to date or to millisecond using swift 4

Tags: swift, firebase, date, firebase-realtime-database, milliseconds

Here, I want to convert the timestamp to millisecond but was unable to convert. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Finally, I found the answer**

**Step 1:** **Add the *[Object Mapper](https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper)* Pod dependency**

**Step 2:**
Create a *FirebaseDateTransform* class with type *TransformType* and override the function *transformFromJSON(...)*

```
//  Created by Bipin on 9/26/18.
//  Copyright © 2018 profyl.org. All rights reserved.
//

import Foundation
import ObjectMapper
import Firebase

enum FirebaseDate {
    case date(Date)
    case serverTimestamp

    var date: Date {
        switch self {
        case .date(let date):
            return date
        case .serverTimestamp:
            return Date()
        }
    }
}

class FirebaseDateTransform: TransformType {
    public typealias Object = FirebaseDate
    public typealias JSON = Any

    open func transformFromJSON(_ value: Any?) -> FirebaseDate? {
        switch value {
        case is [AnyHashable: Any]?:
            return .serverTimestamp
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }

    open func transformToJSON(_ value: FirebaseDate?) -> Any? {
        switch value {
        case .serverTimestamp?:
            return ServerValue.timestamp()
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }


    open func getFirebaseTimestamp()->String{

        return String(transformFromJSON(ServerValue.timestamp())!.date.toMillis())

    }
}
```

**Step 3:**
Extension to convert *date to millisecond*.

```
extension Date {
    func toMillis() -> Int64! {
        return Int64(self.timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000)
    }
}
```

Comment: that seems overly complicated to just get/set a simple value.

Answer (score 0):

Extend Date class as follows to convert to Date from timestamp:

```
extension Date {
    var millisecondsSince1970:Int {
        return Int((self.timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000.0).rounded())
    }

    init(milliseconds:Int) {
        self = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(milliseconds / 1000))
    }
}
```

than you can convert your timestamp to Date after fetching from firebase

```
let date = Date.init(milliseconds:object.startDate!)
```

Comment: I am asking about converting Firebase Servalue.timestamp() to data or to millisecond tot the simple data. Please read the question before answering.

Comment: Yes jazzbpn guess I misunderstood, than mapping is the way as you already wrote in your answer. On the other hand, adding a timestamp node with `ServerValue.timestamp()` function may also help you get the server timestamp easier if that fits your requirements. I am using it like `let node = ["item":"value", "timestamp": ServerValue.timestamp()]` . Thanks for the solution by the way :)